# How to serve content from another assembly

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-2

How do you put views and content in a separate assembly that can be referenced from a MvcApplication?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It sounds like you're talking about portable areas.  [Craig Shoemaker](http://weblogs.asp.net/craigshoemaker/)'s [Polymorphic Podcast](http://polymorphicpodcast.com/) had a recent [episode featuring Jeffrey Palermo and Eric Hexter](http://polymorphicpodcast.com/shows/portableareas/), and they discussed portable areas and what they are.

A link to an [article](http://www.lostechies.com/blogs/hex/archive/2009/11/01/asp-net-mvc-portable-areas-via-mvccontrib.aspx) at [Los Techies](http://www.lostechies.com/) appeared in the show notes, which is a great 'how-to' for getting started with working with portable areas.

The short answer is that you need to compile a project with the proper dependencies, and set the build action on all views as embedded resources.

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK, there isn't a straight forward way using webforms (.aspx) as the view. However you can use other view engines (for example [Stringtemplate](http://code.google.com/p/string-template-view-engine-mvc/)) and [embed the pages and images as resources into the dll](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/319292). You will need to implement:

- Your own view engine
- Image and other resource (css, js etc.) serving controllers

Hope it makes sense...

Answer (score 1):

quite simple, when you handle your routing -> route it to the assembly and class that handles this.

but don't forget you have to implement a few things there. i assume you got this figured out.